# Java pagination on a list

Tags: java, pagination

I am using jdk 1.8. I have to repaginate the query result as it has to go through filters before it is returned.For example My queried result is : (spec is the specification here)

```
List<ActReferral> initReferrals = repository.findAll(spec);
```

For info: **pageable** is :

```
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(first, max);
```

Now it is passing through filters as and **preparing a list to return**:

```
List refs = initReferrals.stream().parallel()
                .filter(ref -> statusFilters.get(STATUS).stream()
                        .anyMatch(status -> status.equalsIgnoreCase(ref.getStatusLog().get(0).getState().name())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now **trying pagination on this list**, but it's **it is returning wrong result on "numberOfElements"**.
Here is how I tried pagination on the list:

```
Page<ActReferral> resReferrals = new PageImpl<>(refs, pageable, refs.size());
```

So, it is returning the whole list instead no-of-items expected in the list. For example if the expected page size was 3 and total returned query result was 6. It is returning result from back end is 6.

**What is the right way of paginating a list? I have to use the incoming pagable info and have to return in Page<> form**

Comment: Are you able to send your page offset/size into your repository query? I believe that is the best if you can manage it since it doesn't query a bunch of things and then throw them a way.

Comment: As I mentioned that I have to go through a filtration after getting back the result. If I use the pagable info during all info are correct. But pagination on list returning everything. Not honoring the no-of-element-in-page.

Comment: Does [List.subList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)) do what you want?

Comment: After looking at the [PageImpl source code for spring data](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/da5df3495e20af92d517caefe1900cbe089b4658/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.java#L44), I don't think PageImpl slices the list automatically. I think you have to pass in the list already cut down to the right size. But still, ideally you would pass through your `Pageable` object to spring data when you do the `repository.find()` call.